# How do I prevent snipmate from remapping <S-Tab>?

Tags: vim, snipmate

In my after.vim config I have line:

```
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

I would like this binding to work. However, after starting VIM I type the first line and get the following output:

```
:verbose map <S-Tab> 
s  <S-Tab>     * <Esc>i<Right><C-R>=BackwardsSnippet()<CR>
Last set from ~/dotvim/bundle/snipmate.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

So snipmate is overwriting the mapping. I understand I could change it within the `/bundle/snipmate.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim` file, but that seems really ugly because I've got /bundle in my .gitignore, which seems to be standard practice.

Any ideas on how to override this, or prevent snipmate from binding to `<S-Tab>` ?

Comment: How does after.vim get sourced? Are you using a Vim distribution like spf13 or janas? Have you tried mapping `<Plug>snipMateBack` to something else?

Comment: I'm using something similar to this: https://github.com/astrails/dotvim

Answer (score 0):

To remap the command executed by `<S-Tab>` to `<C-d>` add the following line to your `.vimrc`

```
imap <C-d> <Plug>snipMateBack
```

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, because it works for me. Interestingly, when i use `:verbose map <S-Tab>` with that line in my `.vimrc` it still says that snipmate is binding the key, although when I actually use vim, `<S-Tab>` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The snipmate documentation states you should remap `<Plug>snipMateBack` in your `~/.vimrc`. See `:h SnipMate-mappings`.

Generally using a vim distribution (which you are) is considered bad for new vimmers because it disrupts learning Vim and puts up barriers when a user decides to customize (as you see here). Personally I would suggest you lose the distribution. Go find a [nice plugin manager](http://vimawesome.com/?q=plugin%20manager) like [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and install plugins when you need them. Doing this means you grow your understanding of Vim as you customize it.

If really do want to use a distribution then you should first try submitting an issue to your distributions [issue tracker](https://github.com/astrails/dotvim/issues).